# Adding an original object to new object which contains a list property of the original object

Tags: c#, data-modeling

**Background Info:**

Currently working on a program where I have a custom data models that are used to store information.  Data model1 will need to be added to a new object data model which contains a list property of  Data model1.

**Problem:**

Currently have a function that parses out information from an email and places data into a Act_Email data.  Once the function is complete it return an object of  Act_Email to the function that calls it.  However I would like to make a list of objects based on my Act_Email.  Currently the following code works great until I get into actually adding my Act_Email object to my other object that should house a list of my Act_Email object.

**Act_Email**

```
namespace ActivityCrawler.Models
{
    class Act_Email
    {
        public string ActivityID { get; set; }
        public string ActivityBody { get; set; }
        public string ActivityThreadIndex { get; set; }
        public string ActivityMessageID { get; set; }
        public string ActivitySubject { get; set; }
        public string ActivityWebLink { get; set; }
        public string BulkEmail { get; set; }
        public string CampaignID { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ActivityCrawler.Models
{
    class ActivityDBCollection
    {
        public List<Act_Email> MinedEmailData { get; set; }
        public List<Act_DHG_Staff> MinedDHGStaffData { get; set; }
        public List<Act_Header> MinedHeader { get; set; }
        public List<Act_Attachments> MinedAttachmentData { get; set; }
        public List<Act_Notes_Tasks> MinedNotes_TaskData { get; set; }
        public List<Act_Crm_Leads_Contacts> MinedContact_Leads_Data { get; set; }
    }
}

public static Act_Email Extract_Act_Email(UnparsedData recordList)
{
    Act_Email parsedData = new Act_Email();
    try
    {
        if (recordList.ActivityType != "Notes")
        {
            parsedData.ActivityWebLink = recordList.ActivityWebLink;
            parsedData.ActivityBody = recordList.ActivityBody;
            parsedData.ActivityID = recordList.ActivityHeaderID;
            parsedData.ActivityMessageID = recordList.ActivityUniqueID;
            parsedData.ActivitySubject = recordList.ActivitySubject;
            parsedData.ActivityThreadIndex = recordList.ActivityParentId;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }


    return parsedData;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
 ActivityDBCollection DBData = new ActivityDBCollection();
Act_Email minedEmailData = Helpers.DataParsers.Extract_Act_Email(emailDataModel);
    DBData.MinedEmailData.Add(minedEmailData);
}
```

Comment: You are creating an Act_Email object "minedEmailData" then trying to add minedContact_Leads_Data that doesn't exist in the code or am I missing something?

Comment: @simon sorry I fixed the code, but that it the idea I am getting an object which I would like to add to another object which will house a list of my object

Comment: Try what dpimente has suggested. If that doesn't work, try making the Lists in ActivityDBCollection virtual e.g. public virtual List<Act_Email> MinedEmailData { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having an issue '*adding my Act_Email object to my other object that should house a list of my Act_Email object*.'

It appears your other object (*DBData.MinedContact_Leads_Data*, where DBData is '*ActivityDBCollection*' ) does contain a List of the Act_email class.

Also in your function 'Extract_Act_Email' you're are always creating an Act_Email object so one should be returned.

Is this a null reference error? I'd check your class initializer for ActivityDBCollection or manually initialize the field 'MinedEmailData' like so

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    ActivityDBCollection DBData = new ActivityDBCollection();
    DBData.MinedEmailData = new List<Act_Email>();
    Act_Email minedEmailData = Helpers.DataParsers.Extract_Act_Email(emailDataModel);
    DBData.MinedEmailData.Add(minedEmailData);
}
```